# Get msbuild changed files list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm building a .net project using MSBuild and msbuild properties file that looks like this:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Compile" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
    <BuildArtifactsDir Include="$(WORKSPACE)\artifacts" />
    <FilesWritten Include="@(EndFiles)" />
    <BuildArtifactsREsult Include="F:\BuildArtifactsREsult\$(JenkinsArtifactLocation)" />
    <SolutionFile Include="$(WORKSPACE)\$(SourceFolder).sln" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <SourceFolder Condition=" '$(SourceFolder)' == '' ">$(JOB_NAME)</SourceFolder>
    <JenkinsArtifactLocation Condition=" '$(JenkinsArtifactLocation)' == '' ">$(JOB_NAME)</JenkinsArtifactLocation>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <BuildPlatform Condition=" '$(BuildPlatform)' == '' ">Any CPU</BuildPlatform>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="Init">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionFile)" Targets="Build"
            Properties="OutDir=%(BuildArtifactsDir.FullPath);Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(BuildPlatform)" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesWritten Include="@(EndFiles)" />
        <FilesWritten Remove="@(StartFiles)"/>
    </ItemGroup>        
            <Message Text="FileWrites: @(FileWrites)" Importance="high"/>
</Target>


<Target Name="Init" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
    <MakeDir Directories="@(BuildArtifactsDir)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="@(BuildArtifactsREsult)" Condition="!Exists('$(BuildArtifactsREsult)')"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(BuildArtifactsDir)" />
</Target>
```

I need to get a list of files that was changed after build.
It should look like I've changes a classes A, B, so A.dll and B.dll were rebuilded and I get in my output something like "Changed files: A.dll, B.ll".
It would be really nice if I could output it to a file.
I've tried to follow the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050110/obtain-output-files-from-a-msbuild-project) but it didn't worked for me, I'm getting an error "

> F:\msbuild\test.msbuild(5,17): error MSB4066: The attribute "Remove"
>   in element  is unrecognized."

If I remove this attribute I'm getting an empty output.

Comment: Could you show how do you fill `@(EndFiles)`? Also I don't see where you put anything inside `@(StartFiles)`.

Comment: That's the whole script, so I guess I don't put anything there. How can I fix this?